# React App Prevent Rerender of All Items in Grid When Redux Updates

Tags: reactjs, redux, grid, rerender

I've got an app that shows a list of items in a grid. Some of the items have an embedded video which flashes or stops playing (if it's already playing) when it's rerendered.

The list is maintained in Redux. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the page it loads more results which causes the Redux state to update which, in turn, causes the grid to rerender all of the items plus the new items.

I'm looking for a solution that will just add more items to the end of the grid instead of rerendering everything.

I've got a component that holds the entire grid. It renders a component for each item in the grid. In each item I have a component that holds the embedded video.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If each item in the grid is a component, like you said, you should use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) (for functional compoents) or [Reat.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) (for class components). It will prevent the component from rerendering if the props have not changed. I can't guarantee your videos will keep playing, but if the only reason they stop playing or flash is because the component is being rerendered then it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help: when passing information from redux to your component, try to update the list of the objects instead of sending a new one

It's redux UpdateObject method.